# Pygame music pause/unpause toggle

Tags: python, pygame, toggle, keypress

Okay here's my code:

```
def toggleMusic():

    if pygame.mixer.music.get_busy():
        pygame.mixer.music.pause()

    else:
        pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
```

---event handling---

if pressed 'm' it should toggle whether the music is paused and not paused

```
toggleMusic()
```

It can pause the music but not unpause, any explanation?

Comment: Have you tried printing the value of get_busy to confirm it's False once the music is paused?

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. For others' reference, my solution was to use a simple class.

```
class Pause(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.paused = pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()

    def toggle(self):
        if self.paused:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
        if not self.paused:
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
        self.paused = not self.paused

# Instantiate.

PAUSE = Pause()

# Detect a key. Call toggle method.

PAUSE.toggle()
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't unpause the music because `pygame.mixer.music.pause()` doesn't affect the state of `pygame.mixer.music.get_busy()`.

To get the behavior you are looking for you will need to your maintain your own variable which keeps track of the paused/unpaused state. You can do this in a class:

```
class mixerWrapper():

    def __init__(self):
        self.IsPaused = False

    def toggleMusic(self):
        if self.IsPaused:
            pygame.mixer.music.unpause()
            self.IsPaused = False
        else:
            pygame.mixer.music.pause()
            self.IsPaused = True
```

Comment: You need to fix your indents. Virtually every line in your `toggleMusic` method is indented incorrectly. Creating a separate class just for this may also be overkill.

Comment: @elParaguayo fixed, thanks. Ya agreed it might be overkill, you could also just hold pass a IsPaused variable into `toggleMusic`

Answer (score 0):

this one is good, i use it for games

source https://youtu.be/kzTloDq1FiQ

```
is_paused = False

def toggle_pause():
    global is_paused
    if is_paused == True:
        is_paused = False
    else:
        is_paused = True

wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(toggle_pause, " ")

while True:
    if not is_paused:
        bob.fd(1)
        bob.lt(1)
    else:
        wn.update()
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem?